# Nuxt Js Event Fires Twice

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-events

I am using Nuxt js SSR for an app that am build, I installed Vue Event plugin but when i emit an event it runs twice at the listener. Created hook runs twice too.

Modules am using:
Axios, Auth, Toast

**Child Component**

```
methods: {
  initPlaylist(songs) {
    console.log(songs)
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.$events.$on('playAll', data => {
    this.initPlaylist(data.songs) //runs twice
  })
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
method () {
    playAll (songs) {
      this.$events.$emit('playAll', songs)
  }
 }
```

How can i resolve this issues guys? I need your help.

Comment: `it runs twice at the listener. Created hook runs twice` sounds like there are two child component instances.

Comment: @Sphinx i don't know how that is possible but i just have one child component with the listener

Comment: i have store actions that i dispatch to fetch data, when i navigate to page this store actions are dispatched twice because in my network area i see two request from same component. Maybe if i solve this it will fix the event listener

Comment: getting same issue with event bus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have to call that parent's method on client side only.

you can write code like this to prevent emit on server side:

```
methods: {
  playAll(songs) {
    if (process.server) return

    this.$events.$emit('playAll', songs)
  }
}
```

or do not call playAll method on server side. (eg: created, mounted...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to off that event first before.

```
this.$events.$off("playAll");
this.$events.$on('playAll', data => {
    this.initPlaylist(data.songs) //runs twice
})
```